# This right join query is too slow

Tags: mysql

My query of interest is below

```
    SELECT COUNT(a.id) 
      FROM users AS a 
RIGHT JOIN date_log AS b 
        ON a.id = b.user_id 
     WHERE
           b.meeting_date BETWEEN '2012-06-01' 
                      AND DATE_ADD('2012-06-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
  GROUP BY a.id
```

However, it's too slow when I try to select data from a large database.
I added 'group by' terms in the query for removing duplicated ids.

Is there better way to do this job?

Comment: Which fields are indexed? Could you give us the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE date_log`?

Comment: thanks for you comments, raina. a.id is primary key. and b.user_id is too. and b.meeting_date also have indexed. (KEY `create_date` (`meeting_date`))

Comment: And, by the way, I wonder why `RIGHT JOIN` is used here?

Comment: I can't tell what you are going for with this query... with just a count, how is it meaningful? Have you omitted a.id from the SELECT list? Are you getting the number of meetings per user in a given time range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the count, you can make this query a left-join, and see if MySQL has a better time executing it (I'm not sure how it actually performs RIGHT JOINs, but I can imagine it in ways which are inefficient compared to LEFTs...

```
SELECT users.id, count(users.id) as user_count
FROM 
  date_log
  LEFT JOIN users ON date_log.user_id = users.id
WHERE
  date_log.meeting_date BETWEEN '2012-06-01' AND DATE_ADD('2012-06-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY users.id
```

Answer (score 1):

First check you have indexes setup for date_log.user_id and meeting_date.

Then have you considdered using 'distinct' instead of group?

```
Select count(distinct a.id)
```